# How to make false postback in asp.net mvc

Tags: postback

I have 
Customer name : "Some Customer"

Country Dropdownlist

If ı choose country

Country's cities dropdownlist

ı can send country dropdownlist selected ıd then ı can show all cities in dropdownlist but customer name dissappears automaticly because of postback

how can ı make postback false in asp .net mvc ?

Comment: this does not compute

Comment: You need to preserve the current value from the POST request.  Or use AJAX.

Comment: using (Ajax.BeginForm("Customer", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }))
ı am using this